# Is there a difference in how && and || are used between Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian, wget

The following runs fine from Debian squeeze, but in Ubuntu 12.04 always returns "Aggregate instance is DOWN" regardless of whether the instance is up or down.

```
wget -O/dev/null -q https://myhost:8443/inst/openid_login.html && echo Aggregate instance is UP || echo Aggregate instance is DOWN
```

I wrote and tested the script in Debian, but need it to work on Ubuntu also. I'm assuming there's some simple substitute I need to make but not sure what

Comment: Should be the same -- did you verify you are using the same shell on both?

Comment: and its possible that the wget versions are different in how they report their status. confirm same version with `wget --version` ? You can of course confirm `&&`, `||` functionality with `true && echo OK || echo nope`, and changing `true` to `false` to see the opposite. Good luck.

Comment: @FatalError yes, I have `#!/bin/sh` in the first line. I tried changing to `#!/bin/bash` although that made no difference

Comment: @shellter yes I did comfirm that with some echo statements and it worked

Comment: GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on linux-gnu. on Ubuntu, the one that doesnt work. 
GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu. on Debian, which works

Comment: possibly even simpler, are you sure it's really succeeding on the box where it always shows up down? since you're using `-q` and sending the output to `/dev/null`, that would be easy to miss.

Comment: after reading your comment about different versions, i tried running the command without the -q flag. Debian shows the successful download, where as Unbuntu shows this SSL error: --2013-03-29 15:37:03--  https://myhost:8443/rti/openid_login.html
Resolving myhost (myhost)... myIP
Connecting to myhost (myhost)|myIP|:8443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
Unable to establish SSL connection. Not sure why one version would accept the cert and not the other, but I guess that's where I need to start

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by specifying SSL verion, like so:

`wget -O/dev/null --secure-protocol=sslv3 https://myHost:8443/inst/openid_login.html && echo Aggregate instance is UP || echo Aggregate instance is DOWN`